# There is a simple poll example with using JSON but it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

There is a simple poll example with using JSON but it doesn't work. 
I don't want to do it with reading JSON from an external file. Where am I doing wrong? Is there anybody write correct way for this example. thank you..

```
 {
  "result":[
  {
    "option":"Lorem Ipsum",
    "percent":"40"
  },
  {
   "option":"Dolor sit amet",
   "percent":"22"
  }
 ]
}

function getData(){
    (function(read_data) {
        percent1 = read_data.result[0].percent;
        percent2 = read_data.result[1].percent;

        $('#pollChoice1').html('%' + percent1);
        $('#pollChoice2').html('%' + percent2);
    }).done(function (){
        $.cookie("choice1", percent1, { expires: 1 });
        $.cookie("choice2", percent2, { expires: 1 });

        $('#pollChoice1').parents().eq(1).find('.col-line-graph').animate({width: percent1 + '%'});
        $('#pollChoice2').parents().eq(1).find('.col-line-graph').animate({width: percent2 + '%'});
    });
}

<div class="col-line">
   <label>
      <span id="pollChoice1"><input type="radio" class="pollCustom" name="pollRadio" value="1"></span><span class="lbl poll-text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-line-graph"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-line">
   <label>
      <span id="pollChoice2"><input type="radio" class="pollCustom" name="pollRadio" value="2"></span><span class="lbl poll-text">Dolor Sit Amet</span>
   </label>
   <div class="col-line-graph"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? From where is the JSON coming? Is it a harcoded variable or coming through AJAX

Comment: You dont need to use `(function(read_data) {` and `.done` unnecesarily.

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the jQuery

```
var read_data =  {
  "result":[
  {
    "option":"Lorem Ipsum",
    "percent":"40"
  },
  {
   "option":"Dolor sit amet",
   "percent":"22"
  }
 ]
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        percent1 = read_data.result[0].percent;
        percent2 = read_data.result[1].percent;

        $('#pollChoice1').html('%' + percent1);
        $('#pollChoice2').html('%' + percent2);

        $('#pollChoice1').parents().eq(1).find('.col-line-graph').animate({width: percent1 + '%'});
        $('#pollChoice2').parents().eq(1).find('.col-line-graph').animate({width: percent2 + '%'});

});
```

And I used a bit of `CSS` otherwise no `div` will be shown.

```
.col-line-graph
{
    height:10px;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1716Lqu/)**